# Terraform provisioning azure windows vmss behind a public load balancer

Tags: azure, iis, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to create a simple windows vmss with iis installed which displays the computer name. For some reason my script isn't running and the public IP address doesn't work. Could someone show me where I've gone wrong please?

**Code:**

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.13"
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

variable "admin_username" {
  sensitive = true
  

}

variable "admin_password" {
  sensitive = true
  

}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg1" {
  name     = "rg2"
  location = "uksouth"

}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vn" {
  name                = "vn-vmss"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg1.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg1.name

}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet1" {
  name                 = "subnet-vmss"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg1.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vn.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]

}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "vmss-pip" {
  name                = "vmss-pip"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg1.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg1.name
  allocation_method   = "Static"
  sku = "Standard"
  domain_name_label = "vmss10101"


  tags = {
    "app" = "scale-set"
    "env" = "dev"
  }

}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic" {
  name                = "vmss-nic"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg1.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg1.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "public"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.subnet1.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    
    
  }

}

resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "nsg1" {
  name                = "nsg1"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg1.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg1.location
  security_rule {
    name                       = "allow-rdp"
    description                = "allow-rdp"
    priority                   = 100
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "3389"
    source_address_prefix      = "Internet"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }
  security_rule {
    name                       = "allow-http"
    description                = "allow-http"
    priority                   = 110
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "80"
    source_address_prefix      = "Internet"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }

}
resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "nsg-assoc" {
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_network_security_group.nsg1
  ]
  subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.subnet1.id
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.nsg1.id

}

resource "azurerm_lb" "vmss_lb" {
    name = "vmss_lb"
    location = azurerm_resource_group.rg1.location
    resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg1.name
    sku = "Standard"
    
    
    frontend_ip_configuration {
      name = "PublicIP"
      public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.vmss-pip.id
      #zones = ["1","3"]
    }     
}

resource "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool" "backend" {
    name = "backend"
    loadbalancer_id = azurerm_lb.vmss_lb.id
    
     
}

resource "azurerm_lb_probe" "http_probe" {
    name = "http_probe"
    protocol = "Tcp"
    port = 80
    loadbalancer_id = azurerm_lb.vmss_lb.id
  
}

resource "azurerm_lb_rule" "lb_rule" {
    name = "lb_rule"
    loadbalancer_id = azurerm_lb.vmss_lb.id
    protocol = "Tcp"
    frontend_port = 80
    backend_port = 80
    frontend_ip_configuration_name = "PublicIP"
  
}

resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine_scale_set" "vmss" {
   
  name                = "vmss"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg1.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg1.location
  sku                 = "Standard_F2"
  instances           = 2
  admin_password      = var.admin_password
  admin_username      = var.admin_username
  

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
    offer     = "WindowsServer"
    sku       = "2016-Datacenter"
    version   = "latest"
  }

  os_disk {
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
  }

  network_interface {
    name    = "example"
    primary = true

    ip_configuration {
      name      = "internal"
      primary   = true
      subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.subnet1.id
      load_balancer_backend_address_pool_ids = [azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.backend.id]
      
    }
  }
}


resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_scale_set_extension" "iis_vmss_extension" {
    name = "iis_vmss_ext"
    virtual_machine_scale_set_id = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine_scale_set.vmss.id
    publisher            = "Microsoft.Compute"
    type                 = "CustomScriptExtension"
    type_handler_version = "1.9"
    protected_settings = <<SETTINGS
  {
    "commandToExecute": "powershell -command \"[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String('${base64encode(data.template_file.tf.rendered)}')) | Out-File -filepath iis.ps1\" && powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File iis.ps1"
  }
  SETTINGS
}


data "template_file" "tf" {
    template = "${file("iis.ps1")}"
}
```

**iis.ps1**

Install-WindowsFeature -name Web-Server -IncludeManagementTools
Add-Content -Path "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Default.htm" -Value $($env:computername)

Answer (score 0):

***We have tried the same in our local and it works fine after doing some modification in your code*** .

*The PowerShell script which needs to be execute inside settings , this is case sensitive we need to use it properly. I have tried to execute PowerShell command directly without referring to iis.ps1 or any variable to it.*

*And after testing extension has been successfully installed with the image we provided in VMSS*  .

You can try with the below;
`main.tf`

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.13"
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}


resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg1" {
  name     = "rg2"
  location = "westus2"

}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vn" {
  name                = "vn-vmss"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg1.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg1.name

}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet1" {
  name                 = "subnet-vmss"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg1.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vn.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]

}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "vmss-pip" {
  name                = "vmss-pip"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg1.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg1.name
  allocation_method   = "Static"
  sku = "Standard"
  domain_name_label = "vmss10101"


  tags = {
    "app" = "scale-set"
    "env" = "dev"
  }

}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic" {
  name                = "vmss-nic"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg1.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg1.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "public"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.subnet1.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    
    
  }

}

resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "nsg1" {
  name                = "nsg1"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg1.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg1.location
  security_rule {
    name                       = "allow-rdp"
    description                = "allow-rdp"
    priority                   = 100
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "3389"
    source_address_prefix      = "Internet"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }
  security_rule {
    name                       = "allow-http"
    description                = "allow-http"
    priority                   = 110
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "80"
    source_address_prefix      = "Internet"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }

}
resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "nsg-assoc" {
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_network_security_group.nsg1
  ]
  subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.subnet1.id
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.nsg1.id

}

resource "azurerm_lb" "vmss_lb" {
    name = "vmss_lb"
    location = azurerm_resource_group.rg1.location
    resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg1.name
    sku = "Standard"
    
    
    frontend_ip_configuration {
      name = "PublicIP"
      public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.vmss-pip.id
      #zones = ["1","3"]
    }     
}

resource "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool" "backend" {
    name = "backend"
    loadbalancer_id = azurerm_lb.vmss_lb.id
    
     
}

resource "azurerm_lb_probe" "http_probe" {
    name = "http_probe"
    protocol = "Tcp"
    port = 80
    loadbalancer_id = azurerm_lb.vmss_lb.id
  
}

resource "azurerm_lb_rule" "lb_rule" {
    name = "lb_rule"
    loadbalancer_id = azurerm_lb.vmss_lb.id
    protocol = "Tcp"
    frontend_port = 80
    backend_port = 80
    frontend_ip_configuration_name = "PublicIP"
  
}

resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine_scale_set" "vmss" {
   
  name                = "vmss"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg1.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg1.location
  sku                 = "Standard_F2"
  instances           = 2
  admin_password      = "Pxxxxx123!"
  admin_username      = "adminUsername"

  

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
    offer     = "WindowsServer"
    sku       = "2016-Datacenter"
    version   = "latest"
  }

  os_disk {
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
  }

  network_interface {
    name    = "example"
    primary = true

    ip_configuration {
      name      = "internal"
      primary   = true
      subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.subnet1.id
      load_balancer_backend_address_pool_ids = [azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.backend.id]
      
    }
  }
}


resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_scale_set_extension" "iis_vmss_extension" {
    name = "iis_vmss_ext"
    virtual_machine_scale_set_id = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine_scale_set.vmss.id
    publisher            = "Microsoft.Compute"
    type                 = "CustomScriptExtension"
    type_handler_version = "1.9"
  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "commandToExecute": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted Install-WindowsFeature -Name Web-Server -IncludeAllSubFeature -IncludeManagementTools"
    }
SETTINGS
}

#data "template_file" "tf" {
#    template = "${file("iis.ps1")}"
#}
```

***OUTPUT SCREENSHOT FOR REFERNCE:-***
[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

*For more information please refer this* **Blog**|[***Install IIS on Azure VM using Terraform***](https://gaunacode.com/install-iis-on-azure-vm-using-terraform) by @*Facundo Gauna* .

Comment: Hi,Thanks I've tried this but when clicking the public IP the IIS page isn't showing.

Comment: ErrorCode: VMExtensionProvisioningError
ErrorMessage: VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'iis_vmss_ext'. Error message: "Command execution finished, but failed because it returned a non-zero exit code of: '1'. The command had an error output of: 'Install-WindowsFeature : The request to add or remove features on the 
specified server failed.
Installation of one or more roles, role services, or features failed.
The source files could not be found.

Comment: Have you tried with the above code . And you need to check extensions ,so that you can see there

Comment: when i was deploying its working fine as you can see , after sometime.

Comment: For more details please refer this [MS Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/451010/vm-extension-failing-codevmextensionprovisioninger.html) once. Also are you trying to put those command in iis.ps1 or directly added the execute command in your code as mine.

Comment: Hello @Dan Wittz, Does the suggested solution works, or still having the same issue.!?